# 24V battery with both 24V and 48V loads

Tags: dc, switching, 24v

I am looking for a simple solution to power my sailboat motor, it’s 48V 12kW, so it’s quite beefy. I have eight 24V lifepo4 cells (4.5kW) each, a 24V DC generator and a 2kW of solar, I would like to draw both 24V and 48V from the bank and also have the ability to charge at the same time.

I was thinking of having two banks, charging one, while using the other. I need a sensible, safe way of handling the switching. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If the voltage is 24V, then you have LiFePo batteries rather than cells.   A LiFePo cell has a voltage of 3.3V.  To get 24V, multiple cells are connected together to build a battery.

Comment: Purchase a 48V charging system.  Connect your batteries to make a 48 V system.  Use a voltage converter to reduce the 48V to 2V to use with your low power 24V accessories.  Contact a company who does this kind of stuff, and see what they say.  You want reliable equipment - it'd suck to be stuck at sea because your home made charger/regulator quit. It'd be even worse if it shorted out and killed somebody.

Comment: Two banks, one to charge, one to use, sucks. Loads which draw on part of the bank suck. DIY charging of Lithium cells sucks, especially if you have to ask. Look at @JRE 's comment and assume it to be an answer.

Comment: The challenge is to keep both 24V packs balanced when using 48V to protect from out of balance or UVP.thus have a boost converter using 24 to 48. 24V off battery and 48V off DC-DC converter

Answer (score 1):

My initial approach might look like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM7N5t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>